# Mysql2 error during upgrade from Ruby 1.9.3 to 2.0.0

Tags: ssl, typeerror, mysql2, ruby-2.0

I have a command line app we use at work that uses ActiveRecord (not all of rails). We want to upgrade to Ruby 2.0.0 to get the load time performance improvement.

To do so, I...

1. downloaded/installed ActiveRecord 3.2.13
2. downloaded Ruby 2.0.0 and change she-bang on script appropriately.

When I run it I get...

```
gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:34:in `ssl_set': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
```

Have I missed a necessary step?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to reinstall mysql2 gem on my system using the RubyGems that came with Ruby 2.0.0.

```
gem uninstall mysql2
/path/to/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/path/to/pkgs/mysql/5.1.46-64/bin/mysql_config
```

Mysql2 was previously installed with an older version of Ruby/RubyGems.